# How to create different interaction modes in JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I'm trying to create a user interface that allows people to change the type of interaction of an element.

For example, when in one mode, the element should respond to click events, when in another mode, the element should only respond to drag events. In another mode, the interaction type may be something else.

At first I was planning on using a `switch` statement, but then realised this wouldn't watch for changes.

I've tried using functions, but when the mode is changed, it responds to both types of interaction, in this case 'click' and 'drag'. I guessed that this might be to do with multiple instances of the same function being called.

I could do it, but my approach would be messy one. I'm looking for cleaner answers.

Ideally, the code would be something akin to (simplicity-wise)

```
switch(modeType) {
   case 'click' :
     //Click stuff here
     break;

   case 'drag' :
     //Drag stuff here
     break;

   default :
     //Something else here

}
```

I realise that AngularJS has `$watch`, which could be useful for this, however I've committed to jQuery for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe how simple it was! In the function, I just needed to call jQuery's `.off()` command to remove all previous event listeners for that particular element.